# how do I "add an argument" to call to eclipse on mac?

Tags: mac, eclipse

I am running eclipse on a macbook pro and it is hanging now and then so I want to run the

> -clean

argument as [described here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html). I would know how to do this on windows but how do I do it on a mac? I can't find the `eclipse.ini` file and in iTerm typing `eclipse -clean` doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eclipse.ini` is located inside the Eclipse application bundle next to the binary. Right-click  `Eclipse.app` (the thing with the eclipse icon you double-click), choose "Show Package Contents", and navigate to `Contents/MacOS/`.

The file `eclipse` in the same directory is the actual binary you should be able to launch with the argument, e.g. `/Applications/Eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean`